# How to make this function tail-recursive?

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

Suppose I've got `fetchPage` API that fetches a page of data and returns a `Future`, for instance

```
case class Page(data: Seq[String], currentPage: Int, hasNext: Boolean) 
def fetchPage(pageNum: Int): Future[Page] = ???
```

Now I want to fetch all the pages and print each page:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
def fetchAll(): Unit = {

  def loop(pageNum: Int): Future[Unit] = for {
    page <- fetchPage(pageNum)
    _ = println(s"page = $page")
    _ <- if (page.hasNext) loop(pageNum + 1) else Future.unit
  } yield ()

  loop(1)
}
```

This function `fetchAll` seems working but it is *not* tail-recrsive. How to make it tail-recursive ?

Comment: Not possible with Future

Comment: Structures like `Future` are among those that are stack-safe by design, they don't need to use tail recursion when referring to themselves and in fact you cannot make examples like your `loop` tail recursive without moving this recursion totally inside a single Future/outside a Future at all.

Comment: Got it. Is this `fetchAll` function is stack-safe ? What do you think ?

Comment: It is. When Future performs `.map`/`.flatMap`/`.foreach` it doesn't create a next nesting level on stack, which in recursive definition could overflow it - it posts a closure with a task on a queue. At each point in time queue (`ExecutionContext`) deals with only one levels of nesting at a time so you can write: `def loop(int: Int): Future[Unit] = Future(int <= 0).flatMap { case true => Future.unit; case false => loop(int - 1) }`, call it with `loop(1000000)` and the stack will be ok. As long as you recur _inside_ a `Future` you are ok. If you recur before creating it, it could overflow.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok Thanks a lot for the response. Good to know that `loop` is stack-safe.